# How can I download a squirrel executable with a get parameter from a rest api?

Tags: express, electron, electron-forge, squirrel.windows

I have a problem, the case is that I want my application made in electron to be downloaded through a url, but with a parameter already entered. That parameter is passed to a rest api via the get method.This parameter must be entered in the executable before downloading it.

Example:

I execute this url in the browser and send it a parameter to my web service https://myweb.com/param1

This link will download my electron application with param1 entered. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.